# Timer flask javascript python, pass python variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, timer

I would like to create a timer. For example, let's say a timer of 5minutes.

I am using Flask and the timer is coded in javascript. I need to define the value of the timer in the python file because this python file is a client opcua supposed to received this value from a server opcua.

The value I want to pass to the javascript file is `timing`. Here is my python code `screen.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    value = "Bonjour"
    title_html = value
    # if request.method=="POST":
    timing = 5
    return render_template('display.html', message=title_html, timing=timing) # render a template at the index. The content will be embedded in this template

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

I decided to set `timing=5` (minutes)

Then this is my `javascript` file `main.js`:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

      if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
      }
  }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * '{{timing | tojson}}',
      display = $('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

In the JQuery function, I am calling my variable timing `'{{timing | tojson}}' and then I execute the timer.

To display this timer, I created an HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/style.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{
        url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>
    
    <title>your dish</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{message}}! Here are some informations about your dish:</h1>
    <h2> countdown </h2>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">5:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the javascript file I chose to set `var fiveMinutes = 60 * '{{timing | tojson}}'` with `timing=5` (from python) instead of harcoding directly in the JS file like that: `var fiveMinutes=60*5`.

When I try with the variable from the python file I got this:

`Registration closes in NaN:NaN minutes!` it doesn't catch the variable from python!
I have no error in the console, just the main.js file has the `statusCode 304` which means it doesn't received the value. How can I manage this issue?